# How to view the data created using gremlin server (from python) in ArcadeDB studio?

Tags: python, gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython, arcadedb

So, i'm trying to connect to arcade db using gremlin server, from a python script, what ever data i create ,such as new vertices and edges, how do i see them through the arcadedb studio?? Currently they are not visible (only the imported database is shown, with open beer data)